# Live vs Living usage in the given example

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, sequence-of-tenses

In Oxfordonlineenglish.com, I found a question in grammar test online as follows,

> ______ spent time abroad when I was a student, I found it easier to get used to ______ in another country.

Options:

1. to have, living
2. having, live
3. having, living
4. have, live

And my answer was,

> **Having** spent time abroad when I was a student, I found it easier to get used to **live** in another country.

But the correct answer given by the website was,

> **Having** spent time abroad when I was a student, I found it easier to get used to **living** in another country.

I'm a little confused here, why **"living"** is correct and why not **"live"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase ***to get used to something*** (don't confuse it with the expression ***used to do something***) requires a noun or anything noun-like in form such as a gerund. And such is the case with your example here. ***living*** is the gerund form of the verb ***to live***. That's why *living* is the correct choice.

Example:

> I just can't **get used to this new mouse** I bought the other day. I think I'm going to still continue using the old one.

Comment: Yes. I confused it with the "used to do something". Thanks for the answer. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Used to" in the sentence presented is an adjective that follows a noun phrase, a pronoun or the -ing form of a verb. It means accustomed/habituated to or familiar with something.

So you say .....to get used to living, not to get used to live.

"Used to" is also used as a verb to refer to repeated actions in the past. In this case it follows an infinitive. For example;

I used to live in London.