# I AM used to doing VS I WAS used to doing

Tags: used-to

What is the difference between "I AM used to doing" and "I WAS used to doing"?

I wonder is that correct:

> **I was used to doing** = I used to do = means in the past and you are no longer doing

and

> **I am used to doing** = I get/got used to doing = means you are still used or accustomed to doing it

?

Examples:

- He used to cycle to his work.
- I was used to typing fast.
- I am used to drinking coffee every morning.
- She got used to the cold climate.
- I'm gradually getting used to it.

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there? Please edit to clarify what you are confused about.

Comment: Take a look at this post first please: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148375/live-vs-living-usage-in-the-given-example/148376#148376

Comment: There is a difference between "I used to do something" and "I am used to doing something".   These mean different things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your examples mix together two different meanings of "used to", which is different from the title of your question.  So I'm not clear exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

some of your sentences are grammatically wrong.

> He had a habit of cycling to work earlier.

Is better than

> He used to cycle to his work.

---

> I am used to drinking coffee every morning.

sounds like you are used by someone to drink coffee every morning, Although
then the sentence would be -

> I am used to drink coffee every morning.

The correct sentence -

> I drink coffee every morning

or

> I have a habit of drinking coffee every morning.

---

> She got used to the cold climate.&
>   I'm gradually getting used to it.

Look correct to me.